# App script not depending on column position

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to be able to insert columns in my data or rearrange column positions without affecting the appscript functions.

Instead of referring to column positions by number, I thought of referring to them by header values (I will not change the names).

I made a small function which will make it easy for writing the code.

The output of the function will be stored in the sheet and then I will copy paste it to my app script function.

Is my approach all right or is there a better way to do it?

```
function get_headers(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  var fin=[];

    var tsheet=ss.getSheetByName("Product");
    var shtname=tsheet.getName();
    var [hd_Product, ...data_Product] = tsheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    for (j=0;j<hd_Product.length;j++) {  fin.push("const "+shtname+"_"+hd_Product[j]+"=hd_product.indexOf('"+hd_Product[j]+ "');") };
Browser.msgBox(fin);
  //tsheet.getRange(tsheet.getLastRow(), 1, fin.length, fin[0].length).setValues(fin);



The below code - for running it for all the shets is not woeking.

  for (i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    var shtname=sheets[i].getName();
    var tsheet=ss.getSheetByName(shtname);
    var [header, ...data] = tsheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    for (j=0;j<header.length;j++) {
      fin.push("const "+shtname+"_"+header[j]+"=header.indexOf('"+header[j]+ "');") ;
    }//for j

Browser.msgBox(fin);


}//for i





//Browser.msgBox(fin);

}

//
//


function process(){

const Product_Code=hd_product.indexOf('Code');
const Product_Item=hd_product.indexOf('Item');
const Product_UOM=hd_product.indexOf('UOM');
const Product_CAT=hd_product.indexOf('CAT');
const Product_Price=hd_product.indexOf('Price');
const Product_Min_Stock=hd_product.indexOf('Min_Stock');
const Product_Lot=hd_product.indexOf('Lot');
const Product_Now_Stock=hd_product.indexOf('Now_Stock');
const Product_Upd_Date=hd_product.indexOf('Upd_Date');
const Product_Vendor1=hd_product.indexOf('Vendor1');
const Product_Vendor2=hd_product.indexOf('Vendor2');
const Product_Vendor3=hd_product.indexOf('Vendor3');




}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to  associate [`DeveloperMetaData`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#adddevelopermetadatakey) with that column:

```
const setup = () => {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
  const setupHeaders = new Map([
    ['Code', 'A:A'],// associate 'Code' with range A:A/Col 1
    ['Item', 'B:B'],
  ]);
  setupHeaders.forEach((range, header) =>
    sh.getRange(range).addDeveloperMetadata('secretTag', header)
  );
};
```

Once setup, the column can be moved anywhere and the associated metadata will also move. You can then retrieve the current column position using [`DeveloperMetaDataFinder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata-finder), even if you change the headers name in the sheet:

```
const getDevMeta_ = () =>
  new Map(
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
      .createDeveloperMetadataFinder()
      .withKey('secretTag')
      .withLocationType(SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataLocationType.COLUMN)
      .find()
      .map(md => [md.getValue(), md.getLocation().getColumn()])
  );
const getColumnsForHeaders = (headers = ['Item', 'Code']) => {
  const map = getDevMeta_();
  return headers.map(header => map.get(header));
};
const test1 = () => console.log(getColumnsForHeaders(['Code', 'Item'])); //returns current location of code and item
```

#### References:

[Developer metadata guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata)

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vA=rg.getValues()
  //Just learn how to use the next 3 or 4 lines and it's pretty easy you can integrate them into any code
  const hA=vA[0];//this is the header row with a [0] index at the end to flatten it out to a single dimension array.
  const col={};//returns column from header name
  const idx={};//returns index from header name
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){col[e]=i+1;idx[e]=i;});//this is the loop to fill in the objects above depending upon whether you want indexes or columns
  //Example of how to use them
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){}) {
    r[idx[headername]];//referring to an index with column header
    sh.getRange(i+1,col[headername]).setValue();//reffering to a column with header name
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to get a column number by header value

An easy way to return the column number would be the following

```
function myFunction() {
  var searchedHeader = "Hello World";
  var column = returnColumn(searchedHeader); 
}

function returnColumn(header) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tsheet=ss.getSheetByName("Product");
  var headers = tsheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, tsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var column = (headers[0].indexOf(header) + 1);
  if (column != 0) {
    return column;
  }
}
```

You can use the dynamic variable `column` storing the column number to perform all kind of requests, e.g.

`var range =  tsheet.getRange(5, column);`

Comment: I am not able to understand how the function will be called or used.  I want to refer to the column position (number) by a variable (name). For example instead of productvals[i][8], I want to use productvals[i][itemcode].  This way, even if i add or delete a column, the code will not change

Comment: You give `returnColumn(header)` the column name and it returns the column number.

Comment: I have six tabs in the sheet, all with connected data -    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Z0Zkx4mBaniD9w9CdrhpB1GRHrkbBHx-FeOy48ax7g/edit?usp=sharing  .... The itemcode appears in many tabs. I need to refer to the itemcode differently for each tab. That's why I designed a name Product_Itemcode or Minstock_itemcode to distinguish the column uniquely (for each tab). All the suggested solution are not much useful for the situation. I don't want to run a function each time I want to refer to a column.

Comment: You just use the function above specifying `var searchedHeader = "itemcode";` and `var itemcode = returnColumn(searchedHeader); ` and then you can do the call `productvals[i][itemcode].` If you have several tabs, than you need to modify the function above to `function returnColumn(header, sheetName) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tsheet=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);...` That it, you need to pass the sheetname to your call. And call with `var itemcodeProduct = returnColumn(searchedHeader, "Product"); ` `var itemcodeSheet2= returnColumn(searchedHeader, "Sheet2"); ` etc